# Shared ViewModel's onCleared() is never called

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have a single Activity application. In one part of the app there is a master-detail combination of Fragments that use [a shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) to share some data between them. The problem I face is that the ViewModel's onCleared() method is not called even when both of the Fragments have been destroyed. onCleared() is only called when the activity is destroyed.

Is this how it is supposed to work? Because that is quite useless in a single Activity model, because the Activity is always alive. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

It would be a little hard to give a solid answer without seeing a little bit of code. My first guess would be that you might have scoped the `ViewModel` to your `Activity` and not the `Fragment`'s themselves.

```
//inside of fragment onCreate()

//scoped to fragment
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)

//scoped to activity
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

If this is the case, if you look at the diagram for the scope of a `ViewModel`. Then the reason why `onCleared()` never gets called is because your `Activity` has never technically gotten destroyed since it is what keeps your app on the foreground.

[image]

If this isn't the right solution to your problem, then I think the docs on [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) might be a good place to start looking for the right answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Indeed I did. Although instead of `requireActivity()` I pass `parentFragment`, but the result is the same, since the parent is the `Activity` for all the `Fragments`. If I pass the fragments themselves then there is no sharing of data, because each Fragment creates it's own `ViewModel`. I guess a shared `ViewModel` is not a solution to my initial problem.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I think if you are needing `onCleared()` to be called in a shared `ViewModel` that can really only happen when the activity is destroyed. What exactly did you need to execute in `onCleared()`? There might be some other solutions to your problem

Comment: I have some shared data that is needed by all the `Fragments` that are accessed from one of the top level destination in my navigation. However once the user leaves this top level destination for another, then this data is no longer needed and should be cleared, so it doesn't use up the memory. I taught `ViewModels` could save this case, but I guess I will just write something on my own, to share data through the `Activity` with the option to manually clear the shared data.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in that activity in `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`, then, yes, that is the expected behaviour. To have a ViewModel scoped only to the master and detail fragments, you would likely need to create a parent fragment for them, e.g., a `MasterDetailFragment`, which hosts both a `MasterFragment` and a `DetailsFragment`.

Comment: It is better to use KTX extensions and `by viewModels`

Answer (score 0):

As the link of [a shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?authuser=1#sharing) from the original question has been updated, but the answers here is not updated. So this is an updated answer based on Andrew Steinmetz's answer.

Below is the way to create that shared `ViewModel` from Google's doc:

```
private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Because it is using `activityViewModels`, the `ViewModel` will have an activity scope. It will be stored in its parent activity's `viewModelStore` after it's being created at first time usage and the ViewModel's `onCleared()` will be called when the activity is finished.

If the `ViewModel` is created as below,

```
private val model: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
```

The `ViewModel` will have only the scope as its fragments, because it is stored in its fragments' own `viewModelStore`, it can survive during the configuration change like screen rotation, but when all the fragments using it are finished. It will be destroyed also.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the scope you are using the ViewModel.

```
private val viewModel: F1ViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

if using above scope of activityViewModels(), onCleared() will be called only after onDestroy() of activity

```
private val viewModel: F1ViewModel by ViewModels()
```

if using above scope of ViewModels() inside a fragment, onCleared() will be called only after onDestroy() of the fragment.